# How can I hide or override built-in code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-snippets

I edit the built in code snippet `propdp` for personal preferences. My problem is that Visual Studio updates reset the edited `propdp` to its default.

I could add a custom snippet with the same shortcut `propdp` but Visual Studio will show me 2 `propdp` options every time I want to use it.

I also could add a custom snippet with a different shortcut, let's say `mypropdp`, but I want to avoid this and just use `propdp` as shortcut.

So, my question is, is there any way to hide or override built-in snippets with the same shortcut so Visual Studio shows only one of them?